# Time elapsed to process a websevice request ASP.Net IIS7

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have an ASP.Net application running under IIS 7.0; we are consuming a third party webservice to complete our business process. The time taken by this webservice to process a requests is too long (some time it take up to 30 seconds). We have contacted our vendor but they keep saying they are taking less than a second to process request at their end. Now I want to check actual time elapsed in processing request and also want to determine any show stopper. Please help me how I can achieve this?

We have a three web servers with a load balancer in our production environment.

Comment: Use the Profiler, Luke!

Comment: Does it happen on production, development environment or both?

Answer (score 0):

Use SoapUI, that will helps in understanding the actual time taken and amount of data transferring.

Check with infra team and see if there any network latency.